# how to install OS remotly using Supermicro IPMI?

Tags: centos, boot, ipmi, supermicro

I have detected server that I can access using supermicro IPMI. I need to reinstall the OS (linux centos 5) because the current OS cannot boot (kernel panic problems). how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- login in IPMI https://IP/page/login.html
- mount CentOS image(Remote Control->Virtual Media)
- open remote control(Remote Control->Launch Console)
- restart server(Remote Control->Power Control)
- change BIOS boot priority order(if need in BIOS)
- install CentOS
- umount install CentOS image

Comment: in step 2, is it possible to download the image from the internet?

Comment: +1 Step 2a - Go to centos.org and download the ISO; 2b - mount the that ISO as mentioned above; 5 - you can also push F11 (might be different depending on BIOS and IPMI card) to select the boot menu.

Comment: @usef_ksa only flope image from your computer...you need use CIFS(SMB) to mount image

Comment: @Chris 2b - mount the that ISO as mentioned above use Windows share

Comment: @ooshro, not sure where you're getting CIFS from, mounting an ISO does not require using CIFS, though the file could be located on network location (performance would suffer worse than 'normal'). Could you point out a reference where it says the CIFS is needed?

Comment: @Chris Onboard BMC/IPMI User's Guide and my experience

Comment: @ooshro, I've only used the add-in cards; the SIMLP line, they must work differently. If that's the case, the questioner might be better off reading the manual for his particular hardware.

Comment: May require changing the mode from UEFI to Legacy Mode to allow the Virtual Drive to appear to the boot menu. SuperMicro at OVH specifically. And they don't offer any assistance for this at all to find out why the device is not available (or which device it is)

Answer (score 2):

This seems rather outdated and not clear on how to install CentOS via SuperMicro IPMI, so I thought I would make an answer of my own.

First, you need to check if your server is compatible with the operating system as on my own I had to backdown from Debian 7 to 6 due to ethernet driver issues. You can check if your SM server is compaitable via [SuperMicro OS Charts](http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/os.cfm) or by contacting your host.

If it is, continue below, if it is not please check what is and use that.

You need to download the CentOS ISO by going to the website and downloading it directly to a folder on your computer. Once complete login into your IPMI control panel, below "Refresh preview" button, click and it shall open a Java Applet.

Now you need to go to Virtual Storage, select tab Device 1 (default). Also ISO from the list and select the ISO file from your computer. Once done, click Plug In then OK.

Reboot your server by going to Power -> Powerdown, then Powerup a minute after. Constantly keep hitting F11 (or whatever you need to hit from your BIOS your screen) and select VIRTUAL DISC, mine is called ATEN VIRTUAL DISC, and it should boot into your OS installation. It may take longer than usual as its communicating between your computer and the server since the ISO is located in your PC.

You may expect some freezes aswell, if you do, don't worry it will take some time, perhaps two hours depending on your options you select.

Once complete, REMEMBER to dismount the virtual storage unless you want to reinstall all over again.

**General Issues:**

- *Error: Malformed IP address.* If you have a 0 in your IP address at the start, for example 3.04.3.2 then make it 3.4.3.2, this shall have no effect after the installation as it will correct itself.
- *Error: Drivers not located* Then you the OS it not compaitable or you will need to setup your own drivers after.